# PHP Password Verify couldn't verifying

Tags: php, passwords, password-hash

i'm doing some types of project to be sent. But now I'll stuck with password_verify method

```
//Login Existed User

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

    //$password = password_verify($con, $password);
    $cmmnd = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' AND password ='$password'";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $cmmnd);

    if ($run -> num_rows > 0) {
        $data2 = $run -> fetch_array();
        if (password_verify($password, $data2['password'])) {
            header("Location: mainpage.php");
        }
    }else {
        echo "<script>alert('ID or Password Are Wrong!');
                                window.location= 'user.php'</script>";
    }
}
```

Above there were the script for login.

Here register code

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
    $remail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['remail']);
    $rpswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rpswd']);

    $hash = password_hash($rpswd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$fname', '$remail','$rpswd')";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    header("Location: regist.php");

}
```

Register are fine but now I couldn't login. I really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance

Comment: In your login - remove the `AND password...` part as this is done in the `password_verify()`.  Also please use prepared statements (and remove the calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`!

Comment: Your register code is wrong. You hash the password but aren't storing or using the hash in any way. You're saving the original plain text password in your db. You should store `$hash`, not `$rpswd`.

Comment: And there's never (even without prepared statements) any need to escape passwords before you hash them since you will only store the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to adjust your registration script. Switch to prepared statements and insert the hash into the database instead of plain text password.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $hash = password_hash($_POST['rpswd'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?,?,?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['fname'], $_POST['remail'], $hash);
    $stmt->execute();

    header("Location: regist.php");
    exit; // always add after header("Location: 
}
```

Make sure that the password field in the database is `VARCHAR(255)` and that the charset is `utf8mb4`. Also make sure that the page you are redirecting to `regist.php` is the correct one.

Then on your login page you must fetch a single field `password` from the database based on the provided email. You can then use that value if it exists to check `password_verify()`. If the hash matches then you can redirect. If not then you display a message.

```
//Login Existed User
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $data2 = $result->fetch_array();
    if ($data2 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $data2['password'])) {
        header("Location: mainpage.php");
        exit;
    }

    // If the login was unssuccesful then display a message
    echo "<script>alert('ID or Password Are Wrong!');
                window.location= 'user.php'</script>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While registration you have generated a hash for the password.But in the login page you are passing the raw password to the select query.